# How to make sequence of images on canvas as if it were Gif with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm making a game with JavaScript and I need to make the character move (a bird), I can move it, but now I want to make it move its wings. I tried to use the gif of a bird, but I could not get the screen to recognize it. (If you know how to use the gif on the screen, this will help me too;)). Then I thought about creating a sequence of images that assimilates to the gif so that when I move the character to the sides change the sequence of images to make the animation.

(https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fw1X9aqadd8U5Sb8yo7M11c1IxnIxPdt)

In the link is what I organized the images in pairs and odd in order to create an if for the pairs are the character turned to the right and odd to the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to create a Sprite image that you can animate with JavaScript. A Sprite is a game creation concept that makes use of a single image with multiple animation 'frames' in the image. There are a lot of tutorials out there already on how to do this. Check out:

http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-sprite-animation/

https://medium.com/dailyjs/how-to-build-a-simple-sprite-animation-in-javascript-b764644244aa